# How do you calculate total impact from a number of correlated events

Tags: probability, statistics

Say that you have 10 events that each have a probability from 0% to 100% and each have a potential impact that is either 0 if the event doesn't happen or a number between $0-$10 if the event does happen. How do I figure out the aggregate potential outcomes for this list, if the events are correlated?

If these events were uncorrelated, we could just draw out 1,024 scenarios with different probabilities and outcomes for each and add them up. However, given that these are correlated, it becomes more complex.

How do we find out the sum of all outcomes of the 10 events? e.g., what are the chances of an outcome of $20, $50, $80?

Thanks!
Dan

Comment: what is the correlation among the events?

Comment: You can still draw up the $1024$ scenarios you mention.  The correlation doesn't change what events can happen, it changes the probability of each combination.  You need to use the correlations to assess the probability of each combination, then add them up in the usual way.

Answer (score 1):

You have to know the **joint distribution** of the events. That is, you should know the probability of each of $1024$ possible scenarios, which can be encoded as vectors $V\in \{0,1\}^{10}$ (where $0$ component means the event did not happen; $1$ means it happened). If this is known, the expected total impact is found as 
$$
\sum_{V\in \{0,1\}^{10}} P(V) \sum_{V(k)=1} I(k) 
$$
where $P(V)$ is the probability of $V$, and $I(k)$ is the impact of the $k$th event.